# add author to section frame beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, author, affiliation

With the following MWE, I am able to create a standalon frame for `\section` that contains only section title. I would like to add also the author of the section with affiliation, exactly like in the title frame, but with a different author than the one of the presentation. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!30,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=lightgray!5,fg=blue!75}
\usepackage{array}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{hyperref,longtable}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,lscape,setspace,url,setspace,morefloats,appendix,comment,booktabs,color}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc, singlelinecheck=false, font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black
}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{romannum}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xspace}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Presentation]{A presentation}
\author[someone]{some\inst{1,2}}
\institute[]{\inst{1} somewhere1 \\ \inst{2} somewhere2\
}
\bigskip
\date{whenever}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section[Section title]{Section title\footnote[frame]{A footnote}} % 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clean up your preamble. There are a lot of unnecessary packages which make your questions unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to look like a title page, use a title page.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!30,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=lightgray!5,fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{section}{parent={title},fg=black}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Presentation]{A presentation}
\author[someone]{some\inst{1,2}}
\institute[]{\inst{1} somewhere1 \\ \inst{2} somewhere2\
}
%\bigskip
\date{whenever}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\title[Presentation]{Section Title}
\author[someone]{somebody else\inst{1}}
\institute[]{\inst{1} somewhere else}
\date[whenever]{}
\section*{Section title} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]